# What does it mean to have a final input parameter in method signature?

Tags: java, methods, input, final

What would be the reason for doing the below:

```
public void processSomething(final String hello, final String two, final Car car){}
```

as opposed to:

```
public void processSomething(String hello, String two, Car car){}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It means that within the method, you can't assign new values to the parameters.

A common reason for wanting to do this is to be able to use the parameters within [anonymous inner classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) which can only reference `final` local variables, including parameters.

Another reason for doing this is if your coding style favours declaring *all* local variables as final if possible. (Personally I try to *treat* them as final, but avoid actually declaring them that way, as it adds cruft.)

Comment: What confuses me is this: I think a final can be changed sometimes. IE, you declare a variable as final so that a button listener can use it. At run, activate that button listener. Then change the variable. Then activate that button listener. Does it not have a different value the second time? If so, why? If not... well, I guess it's really truly immutable and once you tell me so, I won't be confused.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: If you have declared the variable as final, you *can't* change it. If you think you can, you should write a separate question which demonstrates that.

Answer (score 6):

It means you cannot change the references.  String is immutable, but if Car is mutable you can change the fields in that Car, you can't change it to another Car.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that String is immutable by API, but if Car was not immutable, then the fields inside may be changed if not without the final access modifier!

Comment: You CAN change the fields even if the reference is final.  This is where it is different to `const` in C++.

Answer (score 1):

It means you cannot change the references, but it cannot stop the object from being altered.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the reference of this Object can not be changed within the method.